# How to find the closest matching array

Tags: php

Customers of a furniture store website can select products and add them to a "style book". Each product belongs to a "style".
The furniture store has some stylists that each have made their own style book that represents their style and expertise.
I want to be able to find the stylist that best matches a customer's stylebook.
For each style book I have a count of the number of products per style.

```php
$stylists = [
    'Nanda'     => [
        'Design'  => 20,
        'Retro'   => 0,
        'Rustiek' => 0,
    ],
    'Angelique' => [
        'Design'  => 0,
        'Retro'   => 20,
        'Rustiek' => 0,
    ],
    'Lissy'     => [
        'Design'  => 10,
        'Retro'   => 10,
        'Rustiek' => 0,
    ],
];
```

The same for the customer's style book:

```php
$customer = [
    'Design'  => 15,
    'Retro'   => 10,
    'Rustiek' => 0,
];
```

In this case Lissy should be the best match.

The number of products isn't important since this depends on how active the stylist is.
More important is that the stylist matches most of the customer's styles.
For example:

```php
'Stylist'     => [
    'Design'  => 10,
    'Retro'   => 10,
    'Rustiek' => 0,
]
```

Should still be a better match than

```php
'Stylist'     => [
    'Design'  => 300,
    'Retro'   => 0,
    'Rustiek' => 180,
]
```

I have tried giving the stylists' style books scores and percentages based on the order of importance of the customer's style book but still I don't get the best match a 100% of the times.
Google also didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: If there were to be a stylist called Chantal, with following score: `'Design' => '10'`, `'Retro' => '15'`, `'Rustiek' => '0'`, would the higher 'score' on `'Retro'` make Chantal a better fit for the customer than Lissy? Both score equal on `# of matching customer styles`, but Chantal has a higher score on one of the matches.

Comment: @jibsteroos Why? It would be equal at best - its 5 off - the weights are the same (as far as he stated). But it is a valid point. I mean if you want to have more precision then you need different weights - otherwise you have multiple "winners".

Comment: @Gydo Makkinga Well basically you have to weight the values with the customer's preferences and then you take the one that is the least off (in every dimension - each attribute is a dimension in a multidimensional vector). If this solution is not yet good enough you can add more variables to the game.

What did not work btw? What was wrong with your scoring?

Comment: @jibsteroos @ F.Müller I don't want to depend on the count because it could cause one stylist to always be the best match if she has a very high count. It could be used to determine a winner out of two equal matches but I don't mind just choosing a random one of the two

Comment: @GydoMakkinga Well in this case just create a new property e.g. you analyze the stylist and give him a preference score e.g. 300/0/180 would be 480 total so 300 is 62.5% -> thats significant so you can say he is a "major design enthusiast" and a  "minor rustiek enthusiast" (37.5%) -> do that for all stylists and then you can choose one. You just gotta set a threshold for the significance in this case. And compare just these few "compiled ratings". The ratings would be just numbers e.g. 1 (minor), 2 (major) for example.

Comment: @F.Müller My scoring would sometimes give me a completely wrong match. For example : `'Nanda' => [30, 0, 30], 'Angelique' => [0, 50, 0], 'Lissy' => [10, 40, 30]` for customer `[31, 5, 0]` should give me Lissy as match but I get Nanda, Angelique, Lissy.

Comment: @F.Müller that is what I started with. Problem there is that if I only specialise in design it would be 100% overruling all others with a probable better match of 50 / 50 design/rustiek

Comment: @F.Müller I also tried taking the count out of the equation by sorting the styles within a stylist by count and scoring them 1-3. Then by looping over for example all stylists' design and scoring them the same way. That way I should get the biggest design enthusiast

Comment: @GydoMakkinga It should work. Did it not work for you?

Comment: @GydoMakkinga Well ... you have to do the same thing for the customer aswell. If he asks for a mix of "minor design" and "minor rustiek" (1/0/1) you give him a stylist with 1/0/1 or if you don't find a match yet, someone who has 2(+1)/0/1 or maybe 1/0/2(+1) or even 0(-1)/0/1 or 1/0/0(-1). Maybe you need a bigger scale (0-5 or something) and then take the exact match or for a fallback someone who has a similar score. E.g. if the customer wants a 2 in design you don't give him a 5 ... But that all really comes down how you define the model. Calculation is easy as pie.

Comment: I don't think that that's exactly what he means though. Or am I getting it on the wrong end?

He wants to determine which stylist fits best to the customer, except the wrong stylist is being matched.

31, 5, 0 should be matched with 10, 40, 30. Not with 30, 0, 30 because the latter is more specialized in the first and third style rather than the first and second.

Comment: @ChrisvanderGeld He wrote that in the post. The customer has a style-book too. And yes, we talk about exactly that. :)

Comment: @F.Müller Mmh, seems I don't get your explanation then. If the customer has 9, 3, 7. How do I get to the correct stylist? You can hardly start counting numbers because you don't know when to stop or go to the second number.

Seeing the problem in Gydo's comment, It matches with Nanda rather than Lissy. How would he determine the importance of styles? The calculation seems to completely ignore the importance of styles and just match biggest numbres with other big numbers.

Comment: It's not that the numbers have to match. It seems like he's trying to find the one that's closest.

Comment: @ChrisvanderGeld I know that he wants the closest. I am working on an answer - its too hard to go into so many details in the comment section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As we have already discussed, the problem with your model is, that it relies on the number of products. But what we need is an indicator of the style the stylist is using. In other words we eliminate the count and replace it with a relatively weighted indicator (percentages in this case). For example a stylist with a product portfolio of:

```
[
    style1 => 30,
    style2 => 10,
    style3 => 5
]
```

The product count is `45 = 30 + 10 + 5` this will result in a style-profile like this:

```
[
    style1 => 0.66,
    style2 => 0.22,
    style3 => 0.11
]
```

To match the stylist-style-profile with the client-style-profile we need to do the same thing for the client-stylebook `[15, 10, 0]`:

```
[
    style1 => 0.60
    style2 => 0.40
    style3 => 0.00
]
```

The idea behind this is, that we rate how a stylist is influenced by a certain style and the outcome will probably be quite similar for the product that we want to find the best fitting stylist to.

If the stylist made products in a style that is not really what we need for the match, we rate this fact with the weighted relative factor e.g. 0.11. It is not that important, but we still acknowledge the fact that the design might be somewhat biased.

Therefore, if a stylist has a lot of products with a certain style that we are *not* looking for, it won't change the outcome as much.

Please let me know, if this helps and if you want to change anything. From here we could also implement other options and rules.

Below you find my RatingModel.

```
<?php

class RatingModel {
    private $name;
    private $preferences;
    private $preferencesWeighted;

    public function RatingModel($name, array $preferences) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->preferences = $preferences;
        $this->init();
    }

    private function init() {
        $total = 0;
        foreach ($this->preferences as $value) {
            $total += $value;
        }
        if ($total > 0) {
            foreach ($this->preferences as $value) {
                $this->preferencesWeighted[] = $value / $total;
            }
        } else {
            $this->preferencesWeighted = array_fill(0, sizeof($this->preferences), 0);
        }
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getPreferences() {
        return $this->preferences;
    }

    public function getPreferencesWeighted() {
        return $this->preferencesWeighted;
    }

    public function distanceToModel($ratingModel) {
        $delta = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($this->preferencesWeighted); $i++) {
            $delta[] = abs($this->preferencesWeighted[$i] - $ratingModel->getPreferencesWeighted()[$i]);
        }
        return $delta;
    }

    public function scoreToModel($ratingModel) {
        $distanceToModel = $this->distanceToModel($ratingModel);
        $score = [];
        foreach ($distanceToModel as $value) {
            $score[] = $value * $value;
        }
        return sqrt(array_sum($score));
    }
}

$customer = new RatingModel('Customer', [15, 10, 0]);
$nanda = new RatingModel('Nanda', [20, 0, 0]);
$angelique = new RatingModel('Angelique', [0, 20, 0]);
$lissy = new RatingModel('Lissy', [10, 0, 0]);
$mary = new RatingModel('Mary', [0, 0, 0]);
$max = new RatingModel('Max', [12, 0, 5]);
$simon = new RatingModel('Simon', [17, 2, 5]);
$manuel = new RatingModel('Manuel', [17, 8, 10]);
$betty = new RatingModel('Betty', [16, 9, 5]);
$sally = new RatingModel('Sally', [15, 10, 4]);
$peter = new RatingModel('Peter', [16, 9, 1]);

$stylists = [$nanda, $angelique, $lissy, $mary, $max, $simon, $manuel, $betty, $peter, $sally];

$relativeToClient = [];
foreach ($stylists as $stylist) {
    $relativeToClient[] = [
        'stylist' => $stylist->getName(),
        'distance' => $stylist->distanceToModel($customer),
        'score' => $stylist->scoreToModel($customer)
    ];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($stylists);
echo '<hr>';
print_r($customer);
echo '<hr>';
print_r($relativeToClient);
echo '<hr>from best fit to worst (low score means low delta)<hr>';
$results = array_column($relativeToClient, 'score', 'stylist');
asort($results);
print_r($results);
echo '</pre>';
```

Right below are the results (lower values are better):

```
Array
(
    [Peter] => 0.067936622048676
    [Sally] => 0.1700528000819
    [Betty] => 0.20548046676563
    [Manuel] => 0.35225222874108
    [Simon] => 0.3942292057505
    [Max] => 0.50765762377392
    [Nanda] => 0.56568542494924
    [Lissy] => 0.56568542494924
    [Mary] => 0.7211102550928
    [Angelique] => 0.84852813742386
)
```

If we look at the two best fitting stylists we notice, that Peter wins over Sally, because Sally has more Products with a different style.

```
Sally: [15, 10, 4]
Peter: [16, 9, 1]
```

You may also notice, that Nanda and Lissy have the same score:

```
Nanda: [20, 0, 0]
Lissy: [10, 0, 0]

// relatively, for both => [1.00, 0.00, 0.00]
```

They are both regarded equally fitting. Nanda has 5 products more and Lissy has 5 products less of the first style, but it does not matter, because they both only supply one style and this it what matters: How far they are away from the ideal which is the customer-style.

You could also implement the logic so that you have no bias factor and be more strict when it comes to the comparison. In this case you may want to exclude some of the params.

E.g. just comparing `[15, 10]` and `[16, 9]` - in this case Sally would actually win, because she has no delta to the customer when it comes to preferences:

Sally:

```
[
    style1 => 0.60,
    style2 => 0.40
]
```

Peter:

```
[
    style1 => 0.64,
    style2 => 0.36
]
```

Comment: Thanks @F.Müller! This is great! Most of your solution is what I already did except for calculating the distance. This does exclude the count from the equation allowing stylists with less content to still be a match. This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @GydoMakkinga I am glad that I could help. :)